# SNAT PORT Issue

Tags: php, mysqli

I am getting SNAT Port issue. I don't know what to do I am using PHP 7.0 let me show my code

this is my db code

```
function db_connect() {
    $server = 'P:servername'; // this may be an ip address instead
    $user = 'username';
    $pass = 'pasword';

    $database = 'test'; // name of your database

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $database);
    return $conn;

    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
}
```

I am getting SNAT port issue what should I do?

Comment: You really should think about upgrading your PHP version. PHP 7.0 is not supported anymore

Comment: I have done that too

Answer (score 0):

Using Persistent Connections

If mysqli is used with mysqlnd, when a persistent connection is created it generates a `COM_CHANGE_USER` (`mysql_change_user()`) call on the server. This ensures that the re-authentication of the connection takes place.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd.persist.php